# Old Service stopped and new service installed on the same port

Tags: windows, windows-services, port

We have installed a service on a port (443) that was already running an application after stopping it. When the new service is started, the old service should be stopped and the new service should run on the same port (443).

All this is done without rebooting the system.

But this is not working as desired. An exception occurs which is application specific.
I just want to know whether this will work in a generic scenario.

And, is a system reboot required? If yes, why?

Your answers will be of great help.
Thanks for your time in advance.

**UPDATE**:

I am trying to stop an application running on a port currently, not uninstalling it.

Then trying to install a new application on the same and running it.

Windows is throwing a bind error

```
FATAL - 2014/11/21-20:07:36,465 UTC - WIN3C091 - Error during initialization. com.teamcenter.fms.servercache.FMSServerCache 
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind]
                at org.mortbay.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:640)
                at com.teamcenter.fms.servercache.FMSServerCache.startServer(FMSServerCache.java:903)
                at com.teamcenter.fms.servercache.FMSServerCache.instanceMain(FMSServerCache.java:361)
                at com.teamcenter.fms.servercache.FMSServerCache.main(FMSServerCache.java:213)
```

**Note:** 
When I revert back to the previous application, it runs properly. The application is having a cache. Is this a caching problem?

Answer (score 0):

The windows services can be started, stopped, installed and uninstalled without restarting the machine. If the old service is stopped and uninstalled and your new service is installed and started, then the new service should take up the freed up ports. If the ports are not freed up, it may be because the old service was not stopped properly, hence the port occupied.

But when it comes to 443, I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve.

Can you post more details on the same?

Comment: Sorry Hitesh, I may not be able to help you on this. I have no experience with FMS/Teamcenter.

One possible solution could be, trying to stop the service with a command that flushes the cache. (Just a wild guess, check the command documentation for other options.)

Comment: You mean **ipconfig /flushdns** ?